# In a Batch Script execute command to start a web-server and then Launch Default Browser with URL

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, command-prompt

My own batch script is Myscript.bat which is in folder D:. There is a batch file named server.bat which is located at D:\wlp\bin for starting (IBM liberty web) server. And I use the command D:\wlp\bin>server start defaultServer. I want to start the server by clicking Myscript.bat and then want to display a message "Loading Completed" and the automatically a default browser with URL http://localhost:8080/Demo. But after starting the server I am not able to display message  or launching browser. Please suggest what needs to change in my code.(I am not allowed to look into code of server.bat, so it should not be touched)

Myscript.bat contains-

```
@echo Starting script

@echo Loading Liberty Profile. This may take some time ...

@cmd /k "%~dp0\wlp\bin\server.bat" start

echo Loading completed

start http://localhost:%NewPort%/HatsDemo

@pause
```

Command Prompt Screenshot:

```
D:\wlp\bin>server start defaultServer

Starting server defaultServer.

Server defaultServer started.

D:\wlp\bin>
```

Comment: Batch files process commands in sequential order and do not execute the command on the next line until the previous command exits.  You are launching cmd.exe with the /K option which leaves it open and never exits.  Use the START command instead. `START "starting server" "%~dp0\wlp\bin\server.bat" start`

Comment: START "starting server" "%~dp0\wlp\bin\server.bat" start did not resolve.After starting server prompt is returning without showing message or launching browser.

Comment: You may want `CMD /C` instead of `CMD /K`, or you might want to `CALL "%~dp0\wlp\...` instead of invoking a fresh instance of `CMD.EXE`.

Comment: Then you are not doing something correctly.  As soon as the `START` command starts the separate process, which in this case is another batch file, it is done with its execution and the original batch file should continue to process.  I have done this thousands of times.  I literally have hundreds of batch files that run automated like this every day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `call` batchfiles.

**Starting a Program**

See start /? and call /? for help on all three ways.

There are two types of Windows programs - console or non console (these are called GUI even if they don't have one). Console programs attach to the current console or Windows creates a new console. GUI programs have to explicitly create their own windows.

If a full path isn't given then Windows looks in

1. The directory from which the application loaded.
2. The current directory for the parent process.
3. Windows NT/2000/XP: The 32-bit Windows system directory. Use the
   GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory. The
   name of this directory is System32.
4. Windows NT/2000/XP: The 16-bit Windows system directory. There is no
   function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is
   searched. The name of this directory is System.
5. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get
   the path of this directory.
6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

### **Specify a program name**

This is the standard way to start a program.

```
c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

In a batch file the batch will wait for the program to exit. When
typed the command prompt does not wait for graphical
programs to exit.

If the program is a batch file control is transferred and the rest of the calling batch file is not executed.

### **Use Start command**

`Start` starts programs in non standard ways.

```
start "" c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

`Start` starts a program and does not wait. Console programs start in a new window. Using the `/b` switch forces console programs into the same window, which negates the main purpose of Start.

Start uses the Windows graphical shell - same as typing in WinKey + R (Run dialog). Try

```
start shell:cache
```

Also program names registered under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` can also be typed without specifying a full path.

Also note the first set of quotes, if any, MUST be the window title.

### **Use Call command**

Call is used to start batch files and wait for them to exit and continue the current batch file.

### **Other Filenames**

Typing a non program filename is the same as double clicking the file.